# Handle Exception in Jsp

Tags: jsp, exception, struts

Good Afternoon in my timezone.

I am using struts framework in my Web App development.
I had parametrize the exception handling in the struts-config.xml file :

```
<global-exceptions>
    <exception key="sap-error" type="com.galpenergia.sgt.util.excepcoes.chained.user.UserException" path="/globalError.jsp"/>
    <exception key="global-error" type="java.lang.Exception" path="/globalError.jsp"/>
</global-exceptions>
```

And in the globalError jsp i have the following page directive

```
<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>
```

When i try to get the message from the exception object , it tells me that the exception object is null.

```
<% if(exception != null) {%>
    <%=exception.getMessage() %>
<%}else{ %>
<p>Exception object is null</p>
<% }%>
```

Why is this happening ?

Thanks in advance.
Best regrads

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which Struts version are you using. I'm using Struts 1.3.8.

If you are using Struts 1.X you probably need to make sure that you have both exception keys in your resource bundle. Something like:

```
sap-error = Error in SAP.
global-error = Application crash!
```

And in your globalError.jsp you must add:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
...
<html:errors />
```